# install lightgbm GPU in a WSL conda env

Tags: python, machine-learning, lightgbm

-------------------- original question ---------------------------------

How to install LightGBM??
I have checked multiple sources but staill failed to install.

I tried pip and conda but both return the error:

```
[LightGBM] [Warning] Using sparse features with CUDA is currently not supported.
[LightGBM] [Fatal] CUDA Tree Learner was not enabled in this build.
Please recompile with CMake option -DUSE_CUDA=1
```

What i have tried is following:

```
git clone --recursive https://github.com/microsoft/LightGBM
cd LightGBM/
mkdir -p build
cd build
cmake -DUSE_GPU=1 ..
make -j$(nproc)
cd ../python-package
pip install .
```

-------------------- My solution below (cuda) ---------------------------------

Thanks for the replies guys. I tried some ways and finally it works as below:
First, make sure cmake is installed (under the wsl):

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install cmake
sudo apt-get install g++
```

Then,

```
git clone --recursive https://github.com/microsoft/LightGBM
cd LightGBM
mkdir build
cd build
cmake -DUSE_GPU=1 -DOpenCL_LIBRARY=/usr/local/cuda/lib64/libOpenCL.so -DOpenCL_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/local/cuda/include/ ..
make -j4
```

Currently, the install is not linked to any conda env yet. So to do this, under the vscode terminal (or still wsl), conda activate an env and then create a jupyter notebook for testing:
Make sure that `lib_lightgbm.so` is under the `LightGBM/python-package`, if not, copy into that folder.
Then in the jupyter notebook:

```
import sys
import numpy as np
sys.path.append('/mnt/d/lgm-test2/LightGBM/python-package')
import lightgbm as lgb
```

The final bit is you can refer Jame's reply that device needs to be set to 'cuda' instead of 'gpu'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seeing logs about CUDA in the original posts suggests to me that you're trying to use CUDA-enabled LightGBM. It's important to clarify that, as LightGBM supports two different GPU-accelerated builds:

- `-DUSE_GPU=1` (`"device": "gpu"`) = OpenCL-based build targeting a wide range of GPUs
- `-DUSE_CUDA=1` (`"device": "cuda"`) = CUDA kernels targeting NVIDIA GPUs

As described in the project's docs ([link](https://github.com/microsoft/LightGBM/blob/v4.2.0/python-package/README.rst)), as of `v4.0.0` building the `lightgbm` Python package from sources in its `git` repos requires use of a shell script in that repo.

Run the following to build and install a CUDA-enabled version of the library from the source code on GitHub.

```bash
git clone --recursive https://github.com/microsoft/LightGBM
cd LightGBM/
sh build-python.sh install --cuda
```

If you'd prefer to install from a release on PyPI without having to clone the repo, run the following.

```bash
pip install \
  --no-binary lightgbm \
  --config-settings=cmake.define.USE_CUDA=ON \
  'lightgbm>=4.0.0'
```

With CUDA-enabled LightGBM installed that way, you can then use GPU-accelerated training by passing `"device": "cuda"` through parameters, like this:

```py
import lightgbm as lgb
from sklearn.datasets import make_regression

X, y = make_regression(n_samples=10_000)
dtrain = lgb.Dataset(X, label=y)
bst = lgb.train(
    params={
        "objective": "regression",
        "device": "cuda",
        "verbose": 1
    },
    train_set=dtrain,
    num_boost_round=5
)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can install already builded package:

here's notation from official github lightgbm repository:

> Build GPU Version
>
> ```
> pip install lightgbm --config-settings=cmake.define.USE_GPU=ON
> ```
>
> All requirements from Build from Sources section apply for this
> installation option as well.
>
> For Windows users, CMake (version 3.8 or higher) is strongly required.
>
> Boost and OpenCL are needed: details for installation can be found in
> Installation Guide. Almost always you also need to pass
> OpenCL_INCLUDE_DIR, OpenCL_LIBRARY options for Linux and BOOST_ROOT,
> BOOST_LIBRARYDIR options for Windows to CMake via pip options, like
>
> ```
> pip install lightgbm \
>   --config-settings=cmake.define.USE_GPU=ON \
>   --config-settings=cmake.define.OpenCL_INCLUDE_DIR="/usr/local/cuda/include/"
> ```
>
> --config-settings=cmake.define.OpenCL_LIBRARY="/usr/local/cuda/lib64/libOpenCL.so"
>
> All available options that can be passed via cmake.define.{option}.
>
> - Boost_ROOT
> - Boost_DIR
> - Boost_INCLUDE_DIR
> - BOOST_LIBRARYDIR
> - OpenCL_INCLUDE_DIR
> - OpenCL_LIBRARY
>
> For more details see FindBoost and FindOpenCL.
>
> Build CUDA Version
>
> ```
> pip install lightgbm --config-settings=cmake.define.USE_CUDA=ON
> ```
>
> All requirements from Build from Sources section apply for this
> installation option as well, and CMake (version 3.16 or higher) is
> strongly required.
>
> CUDA library (version 10.0 or higher) is needed: details for
> installation can be found in Installation Guide.
>
> To use the CUDA version within Python, pass {"device": "cuda"}
> respectively in parameters.

In short how to build:

1. Install Dependencies:
   Make sure you have all the necessary dependencies installed on your system. For CUDA support, you need to have CUDA Toolkit and cuDNN installed. Make sure your CUDA Toolkit and cuDNN versions are compatible with the version of LightGBM you are trying to install.
2. Update CMake Command:
   Modify your cmake command to explicitly enable CUDA. Update the command as follows:

```
cmake -DUSE_GPU=1 -DUSE_CUDA=1 ..
```

3. build

```
make -j$(nproc)
```

4. install package in pip

```
cd ../python-package
pip install .
```

Comment: This is not correct. Running `cmake` with both `-DUSE_GPU=1` and `-DUSE_CUDA=1` isn't necessary, and running `pip install .` from inside the `python-package` directory is not supported.

Comment: actually, running cmake with these parameters is mandatory because they make it clear that you need to build a library for cuda, I tried and I got the same error, but nothing happened with this parameter

Comment: You need ONE of them, but not both. I know the naming is a little confusing (you might think "CUDA" is a subset of "GPU"), but they are mutually exclusive builds. If you want to run on an NVIDIA GPU, only `-DUSE_CUDA=1` should be used. For all other GPUs, `-DUSE_GPU=1`. I'm very confident about that, it's how LightGBM is tested on every commit: https://github.com/microsoft/LightGBM/blob/b74528f3f7b5b2731920afb09ebd41e8f52fc976/.ci/test.sh#L257

Comment: That's right, thanks, I didn't figure it out right away

Comment: i tried all kinds of pip ways of installing it but it will never work. Need to use cmake which is the only way.