# Problems encountered when installing the gpu version of lightgbm in ubuntu system on wsl2

Tags: gpu, wsl-2, lightgbm

I followed the steps provided by this link ([install lightgbm GPU in a WSL conda env](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77728334/install-lightgbm-gpu-in-a-wsl-conda-env)) to install lightgbm, but encountered a problem.

LightGBMError: No OpenCL device found

I have tried this command `mkdir -p /etc/OpenCL/vendors && \ echo "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvidia-opencl.so.1" > /etc/OpenCL/vendors/nvidia.icd`, But the problem has not been solved

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, OpenCL for GPUs does not work in WSL.

However you might be able to get PoCL running on the CPU in WSL.